# Flush on the board

Tags: rules, learning, flush

There was a heart flush on the board ( A K 5 10 and 7 ) of heart. I had the J & 10 of heart in my hand the other guy had none. I was told that it was a split pot. Was I cheated ?

Comment: Yes you were cheated.

Comment: how can the 10 of hearts be on the board and in your hand at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

More likely you need glasses. Looks to me that you actually had TJ of DIAMONDS. There is only one ten of hearts in each deck, so it wasn't both in your hand and on the board. You'd be surprised, I estimate this actually happens to everybody about once a year if you play regularly. I've seen it hundred of times personally.

Comment: Nicely spotted!

Comment: Many online poker rooms offer the option to use four-colour deck to avoid such misreads.

Comment: I think Mika Caro actually put 4 color decks in L.A. once. Don't think it caught on.